# Why queryString would not give any results even added keyword analyzed fields into query

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

i have a doubt that how query is search into documents.

When i searched with exact query "**what is 1234?**" against the keyword analyzed field,i could not get any results.
but if i searched "**what**" against snowball/standard analyzed field then i got some results and i also tried another way to escape space into the query like "**what\ is\ 1234?**", it also gave some results.

By default what analyzer the query_string will use, whether it will convert user query using any analyzer or it will use what users gave?

please find my gist here: https://gist.github.com/kirubar/6369034

Answer (score 1):

The reason the query string "**what is 1234?**" fails to find results isn't the Analyzer, it's the QueryParser.

`query_string` uses [Lucene query syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package_description).  The query parser will interpret that query as three separate queries.  That is to say

```
"query" : "what is 1234?"
```

Is the equvalent of:

```
"query" : "what OR is OR 1234?"
```

If you want to perform a phrase query, it will need to be enclosed on quotes, something like (I beleive you will also need to set the analyzer to a KeywordAnalyzer, so the phrase won't be tokenized, once again preventing matching):

```
"analyzer" : "keyword",
"query" : "\"what is 1234?\""
```

Or, better yet, don't even use a `query_string` query.  Instead, use a `term` query, particularly when querying on a keyword field, like:

```
"term" : { "message_keyword" : "what is 1234?" }
```